# I want to clear %temp% folder using python. When I am trying to run the script it is throwing a permission error: File is opened in VS Code

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil

```
import os
import shutil
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\Shivji\AppData\Local\Temp"):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
        os.remove(path)
    for dir in dirs:
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, dir))
        shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too experienced in this field but try running VScode as administrator. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

This means in the background a file is opened in Visual Studio . Is your visual studio is open . Can you try to restart your computer and run this code.
I ran your code and it worked fine.